# Data in JSON format to a table in POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Need help with json deserialization in postgresql. I would like this query

`select data from panel`

that returns:

```
                              Data
1 [{"type": "opened","user": "1"},{"type": "added","user":"2"}]
2 [{"type": "added","user": "3"}]
3 [{"type": "opened","user": "3"},{"type": "opened","user":"2"}]
```

instead returned a table:

```
type    user
opened  1
added   2
added   3
opened  3
opened  2
```

I don't quite understand how to represent the empty space between [ and {. I would appreciate any guidance as I have not found this particular example

Answer (score 1):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` to turn the arrays in to rows, then extract the keys:

```
select a.item ->> 'type' as type, 
       a.item ->> 'user' as "user"
from panel
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(data) as a(item);
```

This assumes that `data` is defined with the data type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you have to cast it: `data::jsonb`

Comment: I'd prefer `lateral` instead of `cross` for clarity

Comment: Well it is a `cross join lateral`

Comment: Yes, implicitly, I'd just spell it out. And possibly use a second `from` item not a `join` at all, so `from panel, lateral jsonb_array_elements(panel.data) as a(item)`

Comment: Well, I prefer to spell out the cross join explicitly rather than implicitly using the comma in the from clause (I **never** use a comma in the from clause)